# Pattern matching in android manifest

Tags: android, pattern-matching, android-manifest

I am implementing deep links for android and need to know the pattern for matching the below url

```
<data android:host="*.fa.dk" android:pathPattern="" android:pathPrefix="/Product.aspx" android:scheme="https" />
```

The url will be as follows

1. test.fa.dk/Customer_1/Product.aspx (Should match)
2. test.fa.dk/Customer_2/Product.aspx (Should match)
3. test.fa.dk/Third_Customer_3/Product.aspx (Should match)

where Customer_1/Customer_2/Third_Customer_3 may contain any alphabets/numbers and special characters that are allowed in a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your patter could look like `.*/Product.aspx`. Here `.*` matches any sequence of 0 to many characters.

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="*.fa.dk"
          android:pathPattern=".*/Product.aspx" />
</intent-filter>
```